# Python - Why is this loop to remove items from list not removing all items from list?

Tags: python, list

I have the simplest loop to remove items from a list, and when I loop through the list items and print them, it works as expected.  However, when I try to use the builtin `remove()` (`list.remove(x)`) I get unexpected results:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> for i in data:
        print(i)
1
2  
3
4 
5

>>> for i in data:
        data.remove(i)

>>>> data
[2, 4]
```

What is going on here?  Shouldn't my list be empty?

Edit:  I don't think the answer to my specific question of why this occurs has been answered.  My question asks why the behavior is being experienced, while the other related questions are asking how to properly iterate through a loop.  I feel there is something to learn here that a novice programmer might not understand in reading the related questions.  If there is a question out there that demonstrates what I wrote in my answer, then by all means mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: You shouldn't remove elements from a data structure when using iterators like this.  Although this won't throw a runtime error in Python, some languages won't even allow this behavior.

Comment: There are other good reasons for not doing it this way, as I have just discovered.  I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a logical error.  When my loop removes the first entry in the list, the second entry moves to index 1 from 2, and the third entry moves to index 2 from 3.  Because '2' is now in index 1 of the list, it doesn't get removed, as the loop has already passed on from index 1 of the list.

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question immediately after posting -- the reason for the unexpected results dawned on me as soon as I clicked submit.

Comment: That's alright.  It's good in case someone else faces the same problem.  Gives them something simple to check.  Might I suggest that you accept your own answer?

Comment: I will, but I need to wait 2 days before doing so.